# Best way to compare slice length to uint32 in go (for adversarial context)

Tags: go

I'm writing some inner-loop type input parsing code, and need to compare the length of a buffer to a `uint32`.  The ideal solution would be fast, concise, dumb (easy to see the correctness of), and work for all possible inputs including those in which an attacker maliciously manipulates the values.  Integer overflow is a big deal in this context if it can be exploited to crash the program.  This is what I have so far:

```
// Safely check if len(buf) <= size for all possible values of each
func sizeok(buf []MyType, size uint32) bool {
    var n int = len(buf)
    return n == int(uint32(n)) && uint32(n) <= size
}
```

That's a pain, and can't be abstracted over other slice types.

My questions:  First, is this actually correct?  (You can never be too careful defending against exploitable integer overflows.)  Second, is there a simpler way to do it with a single comparison?  Maybe `uint(len(buf)) <= uint(size)` if that could be guaranteed to work securely on all platforms and inputs?  Or `uint64(len(buf)) <= uint64(size)` if that won't generate suboptimal code on 32-bit platforms?

Answer (score 2):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Length and capacity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity)
>
> The built-in functions len and cap take arguments of various types and
>   return a result of type int. The implementation guarantees that the
>   result always fits into an int.
>
> ```
> Call      Argument type    Result
>
> len(s)    string type      string length in bytes
>           [n]T, *[n]T      array length (== n)
>           []T              slice length
>           map[K]T          map length (number of defined keys)
>           chan T           number of elements queued in channel buffer
> ```
>
> [Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> ```
> uint32  all unsigned 32-bit integers (0 to 4294967295)
>
> int64   all signed 64-bit integers (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)
> ```
>
> There is also a set of predeclared numeric types with
>   implementation-specific sizes:
>
> ```
> uint     either 32 or 64 bits
> int      same size as uint
> ```

---

`len(buf)` is type `int` which is 32 or 64 bits depending on the implementation. For example, for any Go type with a built-in `len` function,

```
// Safely check if len(buf) <= size for all possible values of each
var size uint32
if int64(len(buf)) <= int64(size) {
    // handle len(buf) <= size
}
```

Comment: Why int64 and not uint64?  And does your answer do something slow on 32-bit platforms, or is the compiler smart enough to output one instruction?

Comment: I'm confused.  Those two comparisons have different semantics, but both are correct by the go lang spec which precisely defines the behavior of conversions between numeric types.  If you are checking for overflow, the second one is what you want.

Comment: @user3188445: "Those two comparisons have different semantics, but both are correct by the go lang spec which precisely defines the behavior of conversions between numeric types. " Explain the discrepancy: https://play.golang.org/p/OceveAiuvZs

Comment: First one test if numeric less equal. Second tests if numeric less equal and not negative, which is often what you want. In the case of my original question len can't be negative so doesn't matter.

Comment: It's easy to see that `int64` works in all cases. That does matter.

Comment: I think my minimal example unfortunately does not do justice to the complexity of the issues I'm facing in parsing data.  So for my actual question, `int64`, `uint64`, and `uint` will all work, with `uint` possibly generating slightly better code.  But I have other situations where instead of just `len` there has been a computation that could overflow and lead to a negative number, like I'm actually calling `sizeok(len(v)+1)`.  So for my real use case, `int64` and `uint` don't work, and casting to `uint64` may be the best option.